# Change the order of Bootstrap col-sm-6 blocks on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, block

My code is below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"> First Block </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"> Second Block </div>
</div>
```

This will show the first block left to the second block on devices from small up to extra large and first block on the top of the second one on mobile devices. The question is how do I show the second block on the top if the first one instead without changing their order in the HTMl file?

Answer (score 2):

Use the push/pull classes like this...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6"> First Block </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6"> Second Block </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/128019